# Getting only 3 items of the text block visible on the list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a list box that is scrolls horizontally, it has a text block within, am binding data to the text block dynamically , this data is coming from a server,i have folders coming from the server and am displaying only the names of these folders in this list box.suppose there are 10 folders on the start of the App i want only first three names to be visible on the list(the effect should be something like the Panorama page), then when i scroll next three names should be visible and which ever is closest to the middle that folder should get expanded... and which ever name is highlighted for that name the BG of the list box should change to Green.

Please help me out am very new to WP7

the code am using is

```
 <ListBox BorderBrush="White" Background="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItem}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="36,122,34,500" Grid.Row="2">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <TextBlock Height="75" Width="250" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding WidgetName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achive. Can you create a mockup which shows what you're trying to do? Regardless you will probbaly be better using standard controls in standard ways so that it is clear to the user how to interact with your app and what will happen when they do.

Comment: allow us to see the full code, this above would not achieve the sort of affect your trying to achieve. I would definitely study into Silverlight for windows phone 7.1. As that would give you a better understanding of how you can achieve what your doing.

Comment: am trying to get a horizontally scrolling listbox to display the names of the widgets am receiving from the server and am able to achieve it.. now my problem is i have about 10 widgetnames coming and all of them are bound to the text block inside the listbox...now i wan only 3 names to be displayed on the list and the widget in the center should display its contents in another list box below this horizontal list,, i hope this is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the panorama view, listbox is not your best choice. [Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) has an example called **Panorama/Pivot Sample**.

Check it, i think this is what you're looking for, it describes the method used in addition to sample codes.

Comment: I wan the effect to be something like panorama or pivot will i be able to achieve it??? coz i checked on blend thr s something called pivot item but i didnt undertsand how it worked...

Comment: Yes this example will explain the steps to design such a view, check it out

Comment: i think this will surely work... i was skeptic about it now i have clear idea that this is exactly what i was looking for ... Thank you soooooo much Ameen :)

Comment: Hi... the problem with pivot item is it doesnt end when it reahes the end of the items it is kinda looping like horizontal loop slector.. any idea how to avoid this?? or should i change the control am using??

Comment: I never needed to stop this feature in the pivot view so i'm not sure if we have control over it or not. However, you can read about the details of pivot and canvas in the same sample code page i provided above.